# Where does rustup on Windows look for MSVC and Windows SDK

Tags: windows, rustup

I have multiple Visual Studio installations and they are installed in nonstandard locations on my Windows machine. When I run rustup, it says it cannot find MSVC or Windows SDK, but not how to tell it where these are. How do I do specify where to look and which to use? They are on the PATH environment variable.

Also, doesn’t rust use a LLVM backend? Why doesn’t rustup require an LLVM installation? Or if it does, how do I tell it the location of that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Visual Studio uses environment variables in a similar way as Unix systems. The difference is that instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you have `LIB`, the include path is `INCLUDE`, in addition to the obvious `Path` variable.

LLVM need not be installed for Rust to work on Windows with MSVC.